# Getting int from string in list

Tags: python, python-3.x

I still have some issues concerning editing some values in a list.
My list consist of the following:

```
listInfo = [["Appel",3,"Pitvrucht"], ["Peer",6,"Pitvrucht"], ["Banaan",3,"Exotisch]=, ["Xbanaan",4,"Exotisch"], ["Xpeer",6,"Pitvrucht"]]
```

This is the code sofar.

```
Edit_item = input ("Welk groente of fruit wilt u wijzigen?\n")
            Edit_value = int(input("Welke voorraad komt erbij ?\nIndien een verhoging      toets + (vb:+20)\nIndien een verlaging toets - (vb:-20)\n"))
            for i, nested in enumerate(listVoorraad):
                if Edit_item in nested:
                    if Edit_value < 0:
                        extract_value =listVoorraad.pop(i)
                        print(extract_value)
                        import re
                        int(re.match(r'\d+', extract_value).group())
                        print ("De huidige voorraad van",Edit_item,"bedraagt",)
```

The problem is that i have a list containing strings and floats. Whenever someone wants to change a part of the weight for example peer has 6 kg. Lets say someone wants to subtract that amount with 20 kg. It then needs to find peer take out the hole string part ( list.pop) and then calculate how much is left. When the value reaches zero or less it has to produce a fault. After this its needs to be set in a string again and then appended back into the list.

Anyway of helping me out here ?

Comment: My god! Why don't you use other data container types like dictionaries or classes?!

Comment: Due to the fact that im not that advanced yet. Would be happy to know any other way ;)

Comment: So I would really suggest you to follow this book: http://learnpythonthehardway.org/book/
It will teach you python the `right way`

Comment: Your code is really hard to read. It looks like you're modifying `listVoorraad` while you are iterating over it. This will not work as you expect, or should you have a break after the block containing the pop?

Comment: What is the purpose of `int(re.match(r'\d+', extract_value).group())`?

Comment: int(re.match(r'\d+', extract_value).group() was a way of getting ints from the string. But i deleted it allready. Im looking into other ways to get this done at the moment

Answer (score 1):

Convert your `listVoorraad` into a data structure that is more convenient to edit:

```
from types import SimpleNamespace

listVoorraad = [["Appel",3,"Pitvrucht"], ["Peer",6,"Pitvrucht"],
                ["Banaan",3,"Exotisch"]]
supply = {name: SimpleNamespace(name=name, quantity=quantity, kind=kind)
          for name, quantity, kind for listVoorraad}
```

Edit the `supply`:

```
item = input("Welk groente of fruit wilt u wijzigen?\n")
value = int(input("Welke voorraad komt erbij ?\n"
                   "Indien een verhoging      toets + (vb:+20)\n"
                   "Indien een verlaging toets - (vb:-20)\n"))
if item not in supply:
   exit("unknown item {}, available items: {}".format(
       item, ", ".join(supply.keys())))

current_value = supply[item].quantity
if current_value > value:
   supply[item].quantity -= value
else:
   exit("not enough {item} got {current_value} requested {value}".format_map(
       vars()))
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't have to pop items from the list, and append them to the end again - it can be done in-place using `-=` operator.

```
Edit_item = input ("Welk groente of fruit wilt u wijzigen?\n")
Edit_value = int(input("Welke voorraad komt erbij ?\nIndien een verhoging      toets + (vb:+20)\nIndien een verlaging toets - (vb:-20)\n"))

for el in listVoorraad:
    if el[0] == Edit_item:
        if el[1] <= Edit_value:
            # Raise an error, the value in the list too small.
            raise ValueError
        else:
            el[1] -= Edit_value
```

Comment: problem is that i still need to split the int from the string so i can  calculate with those numbers.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are trying to do something like this:

```
list_info = [["Appel",3,"Pitvrucht"], ["Peer",6,"Pitvrucht"], ["Banaan",3,"Exotisch"], ["Xbanaan",4,"Exotisch"], ["Xpeer",6,"Pitvrucht"]]
dict_info = {k:v for k, *v in list_info}

edit_item = input ("Welk groente of fruit wilt u wijzigen?\n")
edit_value = int(input("Welke voorraad komt erbij ?\nIndien een verhoging      toets + (vb:+20)\nIndien een verlaging toets - (vb:-20)\n"))

extract_item = dict_info[edit_item]
if edit_value > extract_item[0]:
    extract_item[0] -= edit_value
    ...
```